# Align multiple elements with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to do something like that with flexbox:

[image]

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.elem1 {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.elem2, .elem3 {
  width: 75%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="elem1">1</div>
  <div class="elem2">2</div>
  <div class="elem3">3</div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3eww4c3d/)

Comment: Fortunately, there is a great tool on the Internet to do this. [Here is an example](http://flexible-boxes.wstone.io/#~(1~(c~(~2~3))~2~(g~1)~3~(g~1~c~(~4~5)~d~'column)~4~(g~1)~5~(g~1))). Just copy the HTML and CSS, and use it like a boss. :)

Comment: Another good resource to get started with Flexbox ► [A Guide To Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch to `flex-direction: column`.

Add `flex-wrap: wrap`.

Define a height for the container (so the flex items know where to wrap).

Box #1 will consume all space in the first column, forcing the following boxes to wrap to a new column.

No changes to the HTML.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;         /* NEW */
  height: 100px;                  /* NEW */
  justify-content: space-between; /* NEW */
}
.elem1 {
  width: 20%;
  flex-basis: 100%;               /* NEW */
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.elem2,
.elem3 {
  width: 75%;
  flex-basis: 40%;                /* NEW */
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="elem1">1</div>
  <div class="elem2">2</div>
  <div class="elem3">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe (tweak values as desired):

**1.** Using your height (`100px`) & `width`s (`20%` & `75%`):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrap {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.row {
  width: 75%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.elem1 {
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
.elem2 {
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}
.elem3 {
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="elem1">1</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="elem2">2</div>
    <div class="elem3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2.** Full width & height option:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.row {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.elem1 {
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
.elem2 {
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  flex: 1;
}
.elem3 {
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="elem1">1</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="elem2">2</div>
    <div class="elem3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, i don´t want to change my HTML :(

Comment: The layout that you want can not be solved with pure flexbox. You can change the HTML, as Syden says, or you can take an element out of the flex layout (with position absolute)